# CTS Failure android.permission.cts.FileSystemPermissionTest

Tags: android, kernel, cts

For Android-M 6.0.1
The CTS test cases android.permission.cts. FileSystemPermissionTest

1.testDevMemSane

2.testDevkmemSane are failing.

From the file FileSystemPermissionTest.java, it says

```
public void testDevMemSane() throws Exception {
    File f = new File("/dev/mem");
    assertFalse(f.exists());
}
@MediumTest
public void testDevkmemSane() throws Exception {
   File f = new File("/dev/kmem");
    assertFalse(f.exists());
}
```

So, iam thinking device should not show **/dev/mem & /dev/kmem**.

Please help me to resolve this issue.
I am new to codebase,please provide me paths where to change.

Answer (score 1):

This issue needs kernel config changes.

1. For /dev/mem disable config   **DEVMEM**
2. For /dev/kmem disable config   **DEVKMEM**

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines in your config files

+# CONFIG_DEVMEM is not set

+# CONFIG_DEVKMEM is not set